# Splitting data from one cell into many in Microsoft Excel 2010 using colon seperator

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to pull back the words after the colon into new columns, so from the example below i would like Specie in B, jehwejkrhwejkrhwe in C, 07/06/2018 in D, Kim's Wizard Wand Shop in E and Q18FSESPE00374 in F. Any ideas?

[ Product : Specie], [ UMR : jehwejkrhwejkrhwe], [EffDt : 07/06/2018], [Insd : Kim's Wizard Wand Shop], [PolNo : Q18FSESPE00374]

Answer (score 0):

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH(":",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-(SEARCH(":",A1)+1))
```

My formula will have to be applied to the data in each cell.

If might be better to do this on sheet2 at point it to your data on sheet1.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in one of two ways.

1 - With a helper row and two simple formulas:

[image: Screenshot of formula with helper row]

The formula in `B2` is:

```dart
=FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A$1,":",CHAR(1),COLUMN()-COLUMN($B:$B)+1))
```

And the formula in `B3` is:

```dart
=MID($A$1,B2+1,FIND("]",$A$1,B2)-B2-1)
```

2 - With no helper rows but with a complex formula:

[image: Screenshot of formula without helper row]

The formula in `B2` is:

```dart
=MID($A$1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A$1,":",CHAR(1),COLUMN()-COLUMN($B:$B)+1))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"]",CHAR(1),COLUMN()-COLUMN($B:$B)+1))-1-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A$1,":",CHAR(1),COLUMN()-COLUMN($B:$B)+1)))
```

The prettified version of the above formula is as follows:

```dart
=
MID(
  $A$1,
  FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A$1,":",CHAR(1),COLUMN()-COLUMN($B:$B)+1))+1,
  FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"]",CHAR(1),COLUMN()-COLUMN($B:$B)+1))-1
  -FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A$1,":",CHAR(1),COLUMN()-COLUMN($B:$B)+1))
)
```

**Notes**

- `CHAR(1)` was used as it is almost certain that that character will not appear in a string. It could, of course be changed to any other character that you are sure will never be found in the source string.